# iframe as textarea?

Tags: html, iframe, dhtml

I have an `iframe` in an HTML page, how can I cause it to act as a `textarea`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set ***[contenteditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28VS.85%29.aspx)*** property to true

Sets or retrieves the string that indicates whether the user can edit the content of the object.

**Security Alert**:  Users can change the contents of a Web page when the contentEditable property is set to TRUE. Using this property incorrectly can compromise the security of your application. Incorrect use of the contentEditable property might include not validating user input. If you do not validate user input, a malicious user can inject control characters or script that can harm your data. You should take routine precautions against displaying unvalidated user input.

Also take a look at

[Converting an app using document.designMode from IE to Mozilla.](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/ie2midas.html)

Eg:

```
<IFRAME id="txtContent" name="txtContent" src="Content.htm"</IFRAME>
```

and in the Content.htm page

```
<script language="javascript">
    function InitializeIFrame()
    {               
        document.body.contentEditable = true;               
    }
</script>

<body onload="InitializeIFrame();">

</body>
```

Comment: though its great that this answer mentions **security** explicitly, let us not forget, that in most modern browser the user can always edit/modify the DOM interactively. Even in old browsers and with `wget` the user has almost unrestricted access to the data of the webpage, via the source. **any user input should never be validated user-side**. Hence good **security** alert, but indeed a contenteditable will not change the setup